# ReadySetRaphael not rendering SVG properly

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am trying to run http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Continents.svg through [readysetraphael.com](http://readysetraphael.com) and I cannot get it to produce the SVG. It returns the correct size of the div but when you inspect element it looks as if the paths are being drawn off the screen.

I can get it to work if I open the SVG in Illustrator and re-save but then I lose the grouping and Raphael draws the individual paths and leaves the group array blank. I really need to keep the continent groups as I have to interact with the map at continent level.

I have also used different raphael generators and the results are consistent. Has anyone got any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm having exactly the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to want is applying the transforms on the <g> elements to the child elements. [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) can help you do that, while keeping the elements as they are I think.

1. Open the Continents.svg file in inkscape
2. Open menu "File > Preferences"
3. Find "Transforms" section in the dialog
4. Check "Optimized" under "Store transformation:"
5. Close dialog
6. Save file

The transforms should now have been applied to the paths.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I have just ran through your guide and the output still saves with the transforms on the g element. I tried to run it through readysetraphael again but no luck.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126498/apply-all-transform-matrices. No luck with SVGCleaner either though.